# Ubuntu server (VM) with two interfaces. Can only pass traffic on one or the other interface at a time

Tags: networking, ubuntu-10.04, policy-routing

Let me start with a crude network diagram.

Internal Layer 3 switch (Multiple VLANS, including 172.16.220.0 network)  -->  Internal network (172.16.220.0/24) -->  eth1(172.16.220.100)-Ubuntu 10.04 VM-eth0(192.168.1.100)  --> NATed network (192.168.1.0/24)  -->  ASA  -->  ISP.

Here's the problem I'm having on two different servers.  I built the servers with only one interface, eth0, which is connected to the inside interface of the ASA.  I then added another interface for the internal 172.16.220.0 network.  I had a gateway set on eth0 and not on eth1 in /etc/network/interfaces.  I could access the server externally, but not internally.  If I removed the gateway from eth0 and set one for eth1, of course I could access it from internal, but not external.

I tried to set some policy based routing, so that any traffic from the inside network (multiple vlans - 172.16.0.0/16) would be routed back out eth1, but it did not work.  Obviously I'm missing some piece of this puzzle, and have likely mis-configured these servers.  Could someone help me get this to work so that I can access the server from both externally and internally.  I'm getting frustrated at having to use a 3G connection to SSH into my servers to configure!!

Here's my /etc/network/interfaces config:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system

 auto loopback network interface
  iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static

    address 192.168.1.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0

#       gateway 192.168.1.1

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 172.16.220.100

    netmask 255.255.255.0

    gateway 172.16.220.1

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static

    address 192.168.1.100

    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

and my kernel routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
172.16.220.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
default         172.16.220.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth1
```

I had tried enabling IPv4 forwarding in /etc/sysctl.conf, but that didn't work either.

If anything else is needed, just let me know.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT - added kernel routing table after setting static route suggested by faker

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
172.16.220.0    172.16.220.1    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth1
172.16.220.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
```

Comment: This sounds like a problem I've had before. Never really figured it out, though I think in my case it was a hardware limitation. I *think* I solved it for me by adding a physical nic to the virtual host and using that for the VMs. What is your host platform? ESX?

Comment: I've got this machine running on an ESXi 4.1 box managed by vSphere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood everything correctly:

You can obviously only have one default gateway.
You want to have the default gateway on eth0 (which is your external network, right?).

To reach the internal networks you need to setup a static route like:
`route add -net 172.16.X.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 172.16.220.1 dev eth1`

Test if it works, and make it permanent then (not sure how that's done in Ubuntu).

And btw. you have eth0 twice setup in /etc/network/interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for the reply faker-  I tried the static route to no avail.  External works, but still no internal.  Oh, and the double eth0 was just me copying it twice from the config - ignore that!

Comment: Actually this did work - I just hadn't added static routes for all other subnets in the internal network.  I had originally tried to set a route add statement with -net 172.16.0.0 and a netmask of /16, but traffic did not route internally.  Using Alex's suggestion to add each subnet specifically did the trick.  Thanks all!

Comment: Bear in mind though that if you add in a static route for the 172 range you risk locking down access to devices within that network to the speed of the routing interface. It'd be best to remove any routing entries for local subnets to be sure it works properly

Answer (score 1):

I think taker is on the right lines with the static routes, however he's specifying a route to the subnet the server is in which is incorrect. I think what you need to do is set your gateway to 192.168.1.1 and then create a static route for each of your subnets (vlans) using the 172 router address as its gateway. If you need a more detailed explanation of what commands to type please list all your subnets and I'll try to create a routing table for you on my computer in the morning, on my phone at the moment so its a little tricky!

Answer (score 0):

A bit confusing, but it sounds like you need to reach your VM from the host server and vice-versa.

In the VM, add the static route

route add -net 172.16.220.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 172.16.220.100

On the host:

route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.100

I am likely wrong, though.